# Access php temp file with java

Tags: java, php, file-upload, permissions

I like to access an uploaded file which is temporarily stored in /tmp via php.
If I try to access it using the tmp_name from php which is the path I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/php5UY3Ag (Permission denied)
```

The file is there. Otherwise I would get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/php5UY3Ag (No such file or directory)
```

I'm using the PHP JAVA Bridge to hand over the path.
Java is running under apache tomcat and php under the apache web server.

What do I have to do to get this working?

Comment: looks to me you might need to change the access permissions of the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: That's what I did: **chmod 777 -R tmp**. But it's still the same error

Comment: If I move the file with move_uploaded_file() it is working if I refer to the moved file. But that's not really a solution...